# Deserializing name / value pairs to objects

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a collection of name / value pairs where they are defined with the words name and value just like a Key/Value object, i.e.

```
[{"Name":"ActivityId","DataType":1,"Value":"a7868f8c-07ac-488d-a414-714527c2e76f"}, 
 {"Name":"Address1","DataType":2,"Value":"123 Main St"}]
```

If I had an object like:

```
class Request
{
    public Guid ActivityId { get; set; }
    public string Address1 {get; set; }
}
```

How can I deserialize this to the class above?

Should I consider a custom converter? Does Json.NET have something built-in?  Is there a way to decorate the properties with an attribute that I'm missing?  Would it be easier to customize the serialization?

I'm trying to avoid pulling the data for each property from a Dictionary, which would be the easy route, but would require me to do this with each custom implementation.  I would prefer to do this in a base class in a single method using Json.NET (or something in the .NET framework).

I've searched quite a bit, and most examples are real name/value pairs, not prefixed with name and value, i.e.

```
[{"ActivityId":"a7868f8c-07ac-488d-a414-714527c2e76f"}]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Would u be able to decorate the class, in which case something like this will work.void Main()
{
 string name = "[{\"Name\":\"ActivityId\",\"DataType\":1,\"Value\":\"a7868f8c-07ac-488d-a414-714527c2e76f\"}]";
 var request = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Request[]>(name);
 request.Dump();
}
public class Request
{
   [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore, PropertyName = "Value")]
 public Guid ActivityId { get; set; }
}

Comment: Well... it would work if ActivityId were the only field. Unfortunately, there will be many fields and I cannot decorate them all with "Value".  It must match the string for "name" to the property name and then assigned the string for "value" as the value for the property.

Comment: In that case I think writing a custom converter is best bet, sometimes its better to do long way than getting stuck with unwarranted whim.

Comment: @BrianRogers Could be because the question contained the phrase _"What's the best way to go about "_; I have edited that to a more neutral phrasing.

Comment: where's the code you have tried?

Comment: The solution was rather simple - Instead of creating a custom deserializer forcing me to deal with reflection and caching issues, instead, I created a custom serializer that normalizes the JSON to an object instead of a collection of KeyValue pair objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done in a straightforward manner with a custom `JsonConverter` like the one below.  The converter works by first transforming the array of name-value pairs into a `JObject` with properties mirroring the pairs, then populating the target object from the `JObject` using the serializer's built-in `Populate` method.

```
class NameValueConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // Load the array of name-value pairs and transform into a JObject.
        // We are assuming all the names will be distinct.
        JObject obj = new JObject(
            JArray.Load(reader)
                  .Children<JObject>()
                  .Select(jo => new JProperty((string)jo["Name"], jo["Value"]))
        );

        // Instantiate the target object and populate it from the JObject.
        object result = Activator.CreateInstance(objectType);
        serializer.Populate(obj.CreateReader(), result);
        return result;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // WriteJson is not called when CanWrite returns false
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        // We only want this converter to handle classes that are expressly
        // marked with a [JsonConverter] attribute, so return false here.
        // (CanConvert is not called when [JsonConverter] attribute is used.)
        return false;
    }
}
```

To use the converter, just add a `[JsonConverter]` attribute to the target class:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(NameValueConverter))]   
class Request
{
    public Guid ActivityId { get; set; }
    public string Address1 {get; set; }
}
```

Then, you can deserialize as you normally would:

```
Request req = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Request>(json);
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/tAp1Py

Comment: Great solution!  Thank-you.  Didn't know Json.NET had a Populate feature, so another +1 (if I could), because that helps me solve another Deserialization issue I'm facing.